# IBM Cognos reports are requiring a USER NAME when connected to TM1

Tags: cognos

We have IBM Cognos connected to TM1 using an integrated login, however, when running a report, it asks for the user name and password. If we enter the **USER NAME ONLY**, then the report will run fine. If anything else, then the report will not run.

The COGNOS web site recognized me, because the IBM Cognos requires no login prompt and it displays my name at the top of the screen.

How can I get it to run the report and use the Integrated logon and not require me to enter my user name?

The Cognos version i s 10.1.1 and the TM1 version is 9.5.2

Comment: What versions of TM1 and Cognos? Can you connect directly to TM1 with single sign on? Single Sign On can be quite tricky to troubleshoot.

Comment: The Cognos version i s 10.1.1 and the TM1 version is 9.5.2 and yes we can connect directly with TM1 with single sign on.  Please let me know what else to check.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the integrated login was not set up like we had thought.  We have integrated login working now with active directory and now Cognos does not require a username to run the report.

Comment: IntegratedSecurityMode=5?